# "since 1954, we have" VS" Since1954, we are"

Tags: tense

> 1. Since 1954, we are continuously looking to develop new technologies, new processes and new solutions to better answer our customers' needs.
> 2. Since 1954, we have continuously been looking to develop new technologies, new processes and new solutions to better answer our customers' needs.

I saw the first line on the page:[Website](https://silicones.elkem.com/EN/company/About_Us/Pages/Our-values.aspx)
should we opt for the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should opt for the second sentence as the sentence from the Web is wrong
Since can not be used in the present, past and future continuous forms.It may be used in the perfect or perfect continuous tenses.

I have referred to many books and searched on google for the usage.
Nowhere it has been used in the present , past or future continuous tenses with a point of time such as since 1954.

"Since" can be used in the following ways.

`1. It is a long time since I met you.`

`2.It has been a long time since I met you.`

`3.I have been learning English since 1986.`

`4. I have not met you since your marriage.`

`5 .I have known you since you got married.`

`6.I have not read the book since yester day`

But not :"**I am learning English since 1986."**

I will herewith providea link to show how "since: can be used in different ways.

https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/since

Since can be a conjunction and it may be used in the present continuous or in other tense but the usage is different.

Since you are working hard, you will surely pass.

so the given sentence should be:

Since 1954, we have been continuously looking------ because the action began in the past and continuing up to the present moment.This is called present perfect continuous aspect

Comment: I would like to know whether since can be used in the present progress.I want to know why my answer is wrong

Comment: @Mari-LouA.That is progressive and perfective too.I mean present, past or future continuous.I have given the examples too.I have clearly given the example to show that it is not used in continuos(but not perfect continuous).Progressive and perfective are different aspects.The site seems terrible.The typos are there.

Comment: [**Perfect Progressive Aspect** In the present, this aspect is used for verbs that began in the past and continue into the present.](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/perfect_progressive_aspect.htm)

Comment: @Mari-LouAI know.But I should have written that it can not be used in the present ,past or future continuous tense.As the exmples show I know when to use since.It can be used in the perfect or perfect continuous tense